# Images are not reflowing when browser is resized

Tags: html, css

The three images in my code stay in place when the browser is resized. I'd like them to move and stack up instead. I'm struggling to figure out, and any help would be much appreciated.

This is my code (I'm a newbie):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Bad Doc</title>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}

.body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a.item:hover { 
    background-color: gray;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

p {
    font-family: "Garamond", Times, serif;
}

.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 1px;


}
.thing1 {
    border: 1px solid blue; 
    float: left;

}

.content {
    border: 1px solid blue; 
    overflow: auto;

    }

h1 {
    font-size: 72px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    font-family: "Garamond", Times, serif;
}

ul {
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

li {
    list-style-type:none;
    font-family: "Garamond", Times, serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.photos {
    display: inline;
}

img {
    max-width: 30%;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70); 

}   

img:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); 
}

#footer p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>gage</h1>


<div class="thing1">
    <UL>
        <li><a class="item" href=" ">about</a></li>
        <li><a class="item" href=" ">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div class="content"> 
    <div class="photos">
        <a href="google.html"><img src="25612060593_b222234b86_b.jpg"></a>
        <a href="google.html"><img src="25612060593_b222234b86_b.jpg"></a>
        <a href="google.html"><img src="25612060593_b222234b86_b.jpg"></a>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="footer">
    <P>More stuff</p>
</div>

</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some images help to explain your problem will be really helpful for us to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `max-width` set to 30%, use a media query to change this to 100% on smaller screens.

Comment: I'm not really understanding. I added the following but I'm clearing not understanding media queries very well...

    img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }

Comment: Add a line in your media query, for your `img` tag and set the `max-width` to 100%. Move your media query to the bottom of your CSS file, otherwise your general styles declared after it will override the ones in your media query.

Comment: Ah that's perfect. So thankful. And I appreciate the extra bit about moving the media queries to the bottom. I hadn't realized how things would override. Thanks so much.

Comment: My pleasure, enjoy experimenting and learning more. (and tick answer as correct if you think it answered the question :))